# Matlab - Simulink

Tags: matlab, fft, simulink, lookup-tables, numerical-integration

I have a several question regarding MATLAB and Simulink

1. how to calculate characteristic and parameterize the look up table
2. what should be the handle to Matlab function that represent characteristic
3. do I use the right numerical integration to calculate the fourier coefficients

```
function [atemp]=Fourier3(amp,frq)
open('fourier2.slx');
x1=(-1:0.1:0);
x2=(0:0.02:0.06);
x3=(0.06:0.02:0.1);
y1=zeros(1,length(x1));
y2=sqrt(x2);
y3=2*ones(1,length(x3));
x=[x1,x2,x3];
k=[y1,y2,y3];
set_param('fourier2/Sine Wave','Amplitude',num2str(amp));
maxVal = 10;
if (frq <= maxVal)
    disp('Frequency within specified range.')
    set_param('fourier2/Sine Wave','Frequency',num2str(frq*2*pi));
    set_param('fourier2','StopTime',num2str(1/frq));
    simOut = sim ('fourier1', 'SaveOutput', 'on');
    time=simOut.get('tout'); output=simOut.get('yout');
    T = 1/frq;   
    w= ((2*pi)/T);

    for k = 1:10
        f=@cumtrapz
        fun = output.*exp(-1i.*k.*w.*time);
        z = f(time,fun);
        a = 1/T*z;
        atemp=a(1:10,:);
    end;
else (frq> maxVal)
    disp('Frequency exceeds maximum value.')
    msg = 'Error occurred.';
end 
plot(time,output,'b-');
xlabel('t/s')
ylabel('Output')
title('Ausgangssignal Kennlinie')
figure();
stem(abs(atemp),'mo-')   
xlabel('Frequency/Hz')            
ylabel('|Ck|')          
title('Betrag Fourierkoeffizienten')
end
```

Comment: What do you mean exactly by 'characteristic' and 'parameterize the look up table'? Maybe you should include more information about the purpose of your code.